# Flume ng / Avro source, memory channel and HDFS Sink - Too many small files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume, avro

I'm facing a strange issue.
I'm looking to aggregate a lot of information from flume to an HDFS.
I applied recommanded configuration to avoid a too many small files, but it didn't works.
Here is my configuration file.

```
# single-node Flume configuration
# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = avro
a1.sources.r1.bind = 0.0.0.0
a1.sources.r1.port = 5458
a1.sources.r1.threads = 20

# Describe the HDFS sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/%{senderType}/%{senderName}/%{senderEnv}/%y-%m-%d/%H%M
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = logs-
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileSuffix = .jsonlog
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.batchSize = 100
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
#never roll-based on time
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval=0
##10MB=10485760, 128MB=134217728, 256MB=268435456
a1.sinks.kl.hdfs.rollSize=10485760
##never roll base on number of events
a1.sinks.kl.hdfs.rollCount=0
a1.sinks.kl.hdfs.round=false

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 5000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 1000

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

This configuration works, and I see my files. But the weight average of the file is 1.5kb.
Flume console output provide this kind of information.

```
16/08/03 09:48:31 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating  hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/a/b/c/16-08-03/0948/logs-.1470210484507.jsonlog.tmp
16/08/03 09:48:31 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Closing hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/a/b/c/16-08-03/0948/logs-.1470210484507.jsonlog.tmp
16/08/03 09:48:31 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Renaming hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/a/b/c/16-08-03/0948/logs-.1470210484507.jsonlog.tmp to hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/a/b/c/16-08-03/0948/logs-.1470210484507.jsonlog
16/08/03 09:48:31 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/a/b/c/16-08-03/0948/logs-.1470210484508.jsonlog.tmp
16/08/03 09:48:31 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Closing hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/a/b/c/16-08-03/0948/logs-.1470210484508.jsonlog.tmp
16/08/03 09:48:31 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Renaming hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/a/b/c/16-08-03/0948/logs-.1470210484508.jsonlog.tmp to hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/a/b/c/16-08-03/0948/logs-.1470210484508.jsonlog
16/08/03 09:48:31 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/a/b/c/16-08-03/0948/logs-.1470210484509.jsonlog.tmp
16/08/03 09:48:31 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Closing hdfs://myhost:myport/user/myuser/flume/events/a/b/c/16-08-03/0948/logs-.1470210484509.jsonlog.tmp
```

Someone has an idea about the issue ?

---

Here is some info about flume behavior.

The command is
     flume-ng agent -n a1 -c /path/to/flume/conf  --conf-file sample-flume.conf  -Dflume.root.logger=TRACE,console -Xms8192m -Xmx16384m

**Note** : the logger directive doesn't works. I don't understand why but I'm ...

Flume starting output is :

```
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Configuration provider starting
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:sample-flume.conf
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:kl
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: k1 Agent: a1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:kl
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:kl
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [a1]
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Creating channels
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO channel.DefaultChannelFactory: Creating instance of channel c1 type memory
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Created channel c1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source r1, type avro
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO sink.DefaultSinkFactory: Creating instance of sink: k1, type: hdfs
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Hadoop Security enabled: false
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Channel c1 connected to [r1, k1]
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO node.Application: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{r1=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:Avro source r1: { bindAddress: 0.0.0.0, port: 5458 } }} sinkRunners:{k1=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@466ab18a counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{c1=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: c1}} }
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO node.Application: Starting Channel c1
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: c1: Successfully registered new MBean.
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: c1 started
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO node.Application: Starting Sink k1
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO node.Application: Starting Source r1
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO source.AvroSource: Starting Avro source r1: { bindAddress: 0.0.0.0, port: 5458 }...
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: k1: Successfully registered new MBean.
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: k1 started
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: r1: Successfully registered new MBean.
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SOURCE, name: r1 started
16/08/03 15:32:56 INFO source.AvroSource: Avro source r1 started.
```

Since I cannot have more verbose output, I have to suppose that information like

```
[...]
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: k1 Agent: a1
16/08/03 15:32:55 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
[...]
```

indicates that the sinks is correctly configured.

---

PS : I saw followings answers but none of those works (I should miss something ...).

[flume-hdfs-sink-generates-lots-of-tiny-files-on-hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169921/flume-hdfs-sink-generates-lots-of-tiny-files-on-hdfs)

[too-many-small-files-hdfs-sink-flume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815163/too-many-small-files-hdfs-sink-flume)

[flume-tiering-data-flows-using-the-avro-source-and-sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965075/flume-tiering-data-flows-using-the-avro-source-and-sink)

[flume-hdfs-sink-keeps-rolling-small-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145899/flume-hdfs-sink-keeps-rolling-small-files)

Comment: Have you tried if other options for rolling are working fine? Try aswell checking the log right after starting Flume, generally there might be a hint. I have checked your sink configuration against the configuration I was using awhile ago and it seems very similar (we have a bit bigger channel capacities configured, but it should not affect the sink).

Comment: @Serhiy Thanks for your input. I edited my post with the flume's console output. I'm trying to change some rolling information. It seems to be all rolling configuration information which is failing. I actually tried to set the  rolling counr (a1.sinks.kl.hdfs.rollCount=1000) but didn't works. I'm running the HDP 2.3.2, may be a tweak from here ?

Comment: Can you try to setup logging with debug level? In my installation there is `log4j.properties` in `flume/conf` directory. Try setting `flume.root.logger`, `log4j.logger.org.apache.flume.lifecycle` and `log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop` to `DEBUG`.

Comment: Sadly, no way of doing that this works. I suspect a specific configuration setup by a teammates with admin rights. Everything looks correct both for logging (DEBUG nor TRACE) and for rolling. Temporary solution : setup a fresh install, doing the agent working as expected and apply a diff to look for a missconfiguration. Thanks for your input !

Answer (score 0):

Increase batch size as per your requirement

> a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.batchSize =